# Render some text if array.filter returns 0 in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a filter on an array in the render function in a React component:

```
someArray.filter(item => {
    if (item.name.includes(searchText))return true
}).map(item=>{
    return <h1>{item.name}</h1> 
});
```

How can I elegantly display some text along the lines of "No search results" when no items are being returned by the map function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. You can use a ternary operator (and also shorten your callbacks):

```
const filtered = someArray.filter(item => 
  item.name.includes(searchText)
);

//Then, in your JSX:
{
  filtered.length > 0 ?
    filtered.map((item, key) => 
      <h1 key={key}>{item.name}</h1>
    )
  :
    <h1>No search results</h1>
}
```

This checks if there are any filtered results. If so, it will map them to `h1`s that have the `name` of the item. If not, then it will simply render a single `h1` with the text 'No search results'.

Comment: > 0 removed it for me

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is, instead of putting this code directly inside JSX render method, put it inside a method and call that method from render.

Like this:

```
_filterItem(){
    const arr = someArray.filter(item => item.name.includes(searchText))

    if(!arr.length) return <div>No data found</div>;

    return arr.map(item => <h1 key={/*some unique value*/}>{item.name}</h1>)
}


render(){
    return(
        <div>{this._filterItem()}</div>
    )
}
```

**Suggestion:**

With `filter` and `map` you can use concise body of arrow function instead of block body, for more details check **[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)**.

Answer (score 0):

Short and concise:

```
someArray.map(({name}) => name.includes(searchText) && <h1>{name}</h1>)
```